# hide .card-body when childrens has "display:none"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have two cards with collapse.

When the user `clicks` on a letter in the pagination I want the `.card-body` to adapt `display:none` if there are no `divs`to be shown in the card. Otherwise there is always some empty white space below the `card-header`.

the `.card-body` is the `.parent()` of `$('#Categories > .acc-row')`

For now I'm only able to either hide all card-bodies,none of them or just the first one. 
Below is a snippet to my whole code. And here is a [link to a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk5rdb1w/)

Here are snippets of what I've been working on for the last few hours ( none of the snippets works correctly).

```
var toHide = $('div.acc-row');
   if(toHide.filter(':visible').length == 0){
     $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
   }
```

Another

```
if ($('#Categories > .acc-row').is(":visible")) {
           $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().show();
            }else{
           $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().hide();
           }
```

And another

```
 $('#Categories > .acc-row').each(function(){
     if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        $(this).parent().show();
         }else{
        $(this).parent().hide();
        } 
      });
```

And here is my latest approach

```
   if ($('#Categories > .acc-row:hidden')) {
             $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().show();
           }else{
             $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().hide();
           }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#alphf .acco").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
       $('.collapse').collapse("show");

        var cat = $(this).data('cat-type');
        var nam = $(this).data('cat-name');

       if (cat != 0) {
          $('#Categories > .acc-row').hide();
          //$('#Categories > .acc-row:hidden').parent().hide();
           $('#Categories > .acc-row[data-cat-type="'+cat+'"][data-cat-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
           }

            //var toHide = $('div.acc-row');
            // if(toHide.filter(':visible').length == 0){
            //   $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
            //  }

             // if ($('#Categories > .acc-row').is(":visible")) {
             //  $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().show();
             // }else{
             //      $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().hide();
             // }

               // $('#Categories > .acc-row').each(function(){
               //     if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
               //       $(this).parent().show();
               //         }else{
               //       $(this).parent().hide();
               //       }
               //
               // });

               if ($('#Categories > .acc-row:hidden')) {
                 $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().show();
               }else{
                 $('#Categories > .acc-row').parent().hide();
               }

    });
  });



  $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
     //$('button').removeClass('collapsed');
      $('#collapseOne, #collapseTwo').removeClass('collapse');
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('.acc-row').filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });

    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordion_css.css">
    <script src="js/jquery_3.4.1.min.js"></script>

      <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popover.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/accordionFilter.js"></script>
       <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>





    <title>Accordion filter</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
<nav>

  <ul class="pagination" id="alphf">

    <!-- <li class="disabled"><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li> -->
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="A" data-cat-type="A">A</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="B" data-cat-type="B">B</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="C" data-cat-type="C">C</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="D" data-cat-type="D">D</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="E" data-cat-type="E">E</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="F" data-cat-type="F">F</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="G" data-cat-type="G">G</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="H" data-cat-type="H">H</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="I" data-cat-type="I">I</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="J" data-cat-type="J">J</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="K" data-cat-type="K">K</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="L" data-cat-type="L">L</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="M" data-cat-type="M">M</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="N" data-cat-type="N">N</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="O" data-cat-type="O">O</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="P" data-cat-type="P">P</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="R" data-cat-type="R">R</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="S" data-cat-type="S">S</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="T" data-cat-type="T">T</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="U" data-cat-type="U">U</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="V" data-cat-type="V">V</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="X" data-cat-type="X">X</a></li>
    <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="Y" data-cat-type="Y">Y</a></li>
   <li><a class="acco" href="#" data-cat-name="Z" data-cat-type="Z">Z</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li> -->

  </ul>

</nav>


<div class="accordion accordian-wrapper" id="accordionStaff">
  Search: <input id="search" type="text">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <h2 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <h5 class="accordian-title">  Department one </h5>
      </button>
    </h2>
  </div>
<div id="name-cats">
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="card-body" id="Categories">
        <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="A" data-cat-name="A">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Aston</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Tracker</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>aston@some.com </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>Phone:: 1234567890</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="A" data-cat-name="A">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p data-cat-type="A">Arleen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Specialist</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>arleen@firm.is</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p>phone 1239484999</p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="J" data-cat-name="J">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <p data-cat-type="J">John</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Registar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>jj@arn.com </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p> 1234565469</p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="K" data-cat-name="K">
<div class="col-md-3">
<p data-cat-type="K">Kyle
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p>Driver
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>kdrive@company.com
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <p>  1234567890
</p>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
    <h2 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <h5 class="accordian-title">   DepartmentTwo</h5>
      </button>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="name-cats">
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="card-body" id="Categories">
        <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="A" data-cat-name="A">
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="staff_name" data-cat-type="A">Allan</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Specialist</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>allan@lsome.com </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>Phone: 1234567890</p>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="B" data-cat-name="B">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="staff_name" data-cat-type="B">Brad</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>IT-Guy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>brad@some.com </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p> 1234567890 </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="B" data-cat-name="B">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Brent</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Specialist</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>brent@some.com </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p>123456789</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row acc-row" data-cat-type="E" data-cat-name="E">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Evan</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p>Chef</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>evan@some.com </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <p>123456789</p>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- Filter -->
</div>

</div>

</div><!--container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each card body to control whether each row is visible or not. Thus, it is possible to hide the card body if no div is visible.

The whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#alphf .acco").each(function() {

    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $('.collapse').collapse("show");

      var cat = $(this).data('cat-type');
      var nam = $(this).data('cat-name');

      // modified from here down
      if (cat != 0) {
        $('.card-body').each(function(i, cardBody) {
          var hidebody = true;
          ($(cardBody.children)).each(function(f, accRow) {
            $(accRow).hide();
            if ($(accRow).data('catType') == cat && $(accRow).data('catName') == nam) {
              hidebody = false;
              $(accRow).show();
            }
          });
          if (hidebody) {
            $(cardBody).hide();
          } else {
            $(cardBody).show();
          }
        });
      }
      // modified from here up

    });

  });

  $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    $('#collapseOne, #collapseTwo').removeClass('collapse');
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.acc-row').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

});
```

In addition, you must not have more than one same id attribute on the same page. So I recommend you to remove or modify the id `#Categories`.